# Set up the database structure and populate it using the SQL dump given

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

How can i set up the database structure and populate it using the SQL dump file given or is there a way to import the tables into migrations that i got in phpmyadmin by writing the sql commands ?

Comment: https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204403864/export-and-import-mysql-databases ? You can import straight from phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have sql file you can import it into your database using the below command

```
1.Create a database
2.Open XAMPP shell

Enter this commands
 #1->mysql -u root
 #2.use your_database_name
 #3.source path_to_sql_file (without double quotes)
 #4.hit enter button.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer , but I'm using laragon can you please guide me with the same

Comment: Try this command i'm not sure just give a try
cmd>cd <laragon_path>\bin
<laragon_path>\bin>mysql -u <user> -p <dbname> <filename_with_path>;